# Why is blogdown putting a mamba command through normalizePath?

Tags: r, github-actions, miniconda, blogdown, reticulate

Here's what I'm doing:

1. I have a blog that uses blogdown to render .Rmd files.
2. Some of the code snippets in the blog are in Python. I'm using `reticulate` for that.
3. I'm using a GitHub workflow to build and publish the blog as part of a larger website. This workflow sets up the environment and package dependencies in `miniconda`.

The last time this ran was six months ago. At that time, it worked. Now, it does not. I can't seem to replicate the behavior locally for more detailed debugging.

It seems to be trying to put a mamba command into `normalizePath` instead of a filesystem path (`www-main` is the name of the repository):

```
conda activate www-main
Rscript -e 'blogdown::build_site(local=FALSE, run_hugo=FALSE, build_rmd="content/blog/2020-08-28-api.Rmd")' 
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -l {0}
  env:
    CONDA_PKGS_DIR: /home/runner/conda_pkgs_dir
Rendering content/blog/2020-08-28-api.Rmd...
[...]
Quitting from lines 401-410 (2020-08-28-api.Rmd) 
Error in normalizePath(conda, winslash = "/", mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="# cmd: /usr/share/miniconda/condabin/mamba update --name www-main --file /home/runner/work/www-main/www-main/conda": No such file or directory
Calls: local ... python_munge_path -> get_python_conda_info -> normalizePath
Execution halted
Error: Failed to render content/blog/2020-08-28-api.Rmd
Execution halted
```

Lines 401-410 of `2020-08-28-api.Rmd` are a Python code block:

````
400 ```{python python-data, dev='svg'}
401 import covidcast
402 from datetime import date
403 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
404 
405 data = covidcast.signal("fb-survey", "smoothed_hh_cmnty_cli",
406                         date(2020, 9, 8), date(2020, 9, 8),
407                         geo_type="state")
408 covidcast.plot_choropleth(data, figsize=(7, 5))
409 plt.title("% who know someone who is sick, Sept 8, 2020")
410 ```
````

The useful bits of the output of `conda info`, in case it helps:

```
     active environment : www-main
    active env location : /usr/share/miniconda/envs/www-main
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/runner/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/runner/.condarc
          conda version : 4.12.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.12.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=5.15.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /usr/share/miniconda  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /usr/share/miniconda/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/runner/conda_pkgs_dir
       envs directories : /usr/share/miniconda/envs
                          /home/runner/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.12.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.12 Linux/5.15.0-1020-azure ubuntu/20.04.5 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1001:121
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

- I found this, but their workaround doesn't make sense for me since I'm not using papermill: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1184
- I found this, but my paths don't have spaces: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1149
- I found this, but their problem includes an entirely reasonable value for `path[1]`, unlike mine: [How can I tell R where the conda environment is via a docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73741923/how-can-i-tell-r-where-the-conda-environment-is-via-a-docker-image)

The build environment for this is a bit of a bear but I can probably put together a minimum working (/nonworking) example if needed, lmk

Answer (score 0):

[I tracked this down to at least two bits of weird/buggy behavior in `reticulate`](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1293) and found a workaround: switch from vanilla miniconda to Mambaforge.

The TL;DR seems to be that whatever wacky ubuntu-latest setup-miniconda@v2 environment started putting into `meta/history` doesn't include a `create` line, which is what `reticulate` needs in order to figure out which conda goes with which python, because (1) it ignores the `reticulate.conda_binary` setting for some reason, and (2) it uses a more restrictive regex to parse the lines of the history file than the regex it uses to select them. Mambaforge *does* include the `create` line, so `reticulate` is happy.

```
      - uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
          activate-environment: www-main
          miniforge-variant: Mambaforge
          miniforge-version: latest
          use-mamba: true
          use-only-tar-bz2: true # (for caching support)
      - name: Update environment
        run: mamba env update -n www-main -f environment.yml
```